# Read Later Feature (with notes?)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Would it be worthwhile to create functionality similar to 'favorites' where you can 'star' any post (not just questions, but answers) and place this 'starred' post in a little bucket on your topbar (perhaps inbox?). The idea here is to create a kind of 'read later' area for posts that you just dont have time to read through entirely (or research all their links/etc). In fact, it would be great if when you click the 'star' a tiny message box appears asking you to optionally add a quick note [to yourself].

I find myself doing this anyway with notepad. For instance, I see a post I like and click the share button (to get the url to just the post) and then plop that in notepade with a brief note to 'talk to joe about this' or 'research more about x [in this post]'.

Am I just being wistful or would this help others?

Comment: This is probably one for Stack Exchange Meta

Comment: Pushbullet? Instapaper? Pocket? There are apps for that.

Comment: there are certainly apps for that but I was hoping for a native feature... also could someone migrate this to meta.SX?

Comment: In general, there's usually no need to migrate to Meta SE because the post will get seen by the same employees in the end. In this specific case, I'm not migrating because the request has actually been made many times before. One instance is [Is there any facility to mark questions as Followups or Flag to look at flagged questions later beside favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91465); another is [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69346). Short answer, it's just never been that popular.